# Why this PHP line not printing the the Error message?

Tags: php

In one of my file I wrote these statements. Instead of printing the error message it generates the page with normal errors.

```
try {
            $var = 90 / 0; // Error dvide by zero
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            die( 'Something really gone wrong');
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PHP error is not the same as a PHP exception. In your script, no exceptions are thrown - only an error occurs.

You could get the same result if you install a custom error handler:

```
<?php
// install a temporary error handler
set_error_handler(function($error) {
    die("Something really wrong");
});

// do something invalid
$var = 90 / 0; // Error dvide by zero

// restore previous error handler
restore_error_handler();
?>
```

If you're a real fan of exceptions, you could also install an error handler that automatically turns errors into PHP exceptions:

```
<?php
// install an error handler that turns error into exceptions
set_error_handler(function($error) {
    throw new Exception($error);
});

// open try-catch block to catch exceptions
try
{
    // do something invalid
    $var = 90 / 0; // Error dvide by zero
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    // oops
    die("Something really wrong");
}

?>
```